# Teamcity getting a reference to the last successful build

Tags: teamcity, artifacts, teamcity-8.0

I have a build configuration which will build an artifact file. What I'd like to do, is add a a step so that after the artifact is built, it will do a diff between it and the last successfully built artifact. I can write a tool that will do the diff as long as I can work out the path to the last artifact file.

How can I obtain details of the last successful artifact?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following link:

> /repository/download/BUILD_TYPE_ID/.lastSuccessful/ARTIFACT_PATH

See more info here: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Patterns+For+Accessing+Build+Artifacts